# Installing SQL Server - HDD vs SSD?

Tags: sql-server

If we put the launch time aside, what are the benefits of installing your SQL server (along with your databases) in SSD instead of HDD?

Comment: You really ask about the difference of "up to around 450 IOPS" (15k SAS SSD) and "20.000+ IOPS"? SSD are regularly - even cheap ones - 100 times faster in IO capabilities. Guess what databases love ;)

Comment: The benefits of SSD are self-explanatory. The downside is cost.

Answer (score 0):

You already know the answer for this, it is FAST.

Here are very basic and known benefits of using SSD.

1. Keep your databases in SSD will handle more IO in very less time.
2. Keep temp DB in SSD, obviously, it will improve the performance of
   the queries.
3. We can use SSD as buffer pool (extension).